# Bootstrap grid system - make column change row depending on size

Tags: html, css, grid, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to get a grid system with behaviour similar to what is on this page: http://weibergmedia.com/demos/yk

You can see that the grid completely rearranges depending on the window size; retaining the column sizes until they are essentially col-xs-12, when the windows size is extra small.

Any pointers to get me working in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. All I can think of doing at the moment is writing a convoluted javascript to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: Are you dead set on using Bootstrap or will [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) be worth learning to you?

Comment: You can achieve this using Isotope, check it out: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I'll have a look at both of these. I can see now that the example page I included in the original post uses isotope. But I'm sure it'd be worth me looking into CSS Grid and Flexbox also. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Looking at Isotope I feel that's the best option. @FurkanPoyraz consider converting to an answer with a small example as that should fit his needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Isotope.
Using it together with the Bootstrap grid system would look like this:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var iso = new Isotope( elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 255px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row grid">
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3 col-lg-6">
      <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```